# Trying to compile a linux-based app on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, linux, macos, compilation, zlib

I'm just trying to compile the linux-based FCEUX (NES emulator) on my mac, OS X 10.5 Leopard.

I got all the dependencies (SDL, GTK+ 2) going and everything but of all things this is now my problem:

```
Undefined symbols: 
"_compress", referenced from: SaveSnapshot() in video.o
"_gzclose", referenced from: FCEU_fopen(char const*, char const*, char*, char*, int, char const**)in file.o
"_crc32", referenced from: CalcCRC32(unsigned int, unsigned char*, unsigned int)in crc32.o
_unzReadCurrentFile in unzip.o _unzReadCurrentFile in unzip.o
"_uncompress", referenced from: NetplayUpdate(unsigned char*)in netplay.o FCEUSS_LoadFP(EMUFILE*, ENUM_SSLOADPARAMS) in state.o
"_compress2", referenced from: FCEUNET_SendFile(unsigned char, char*)in netplay.o FCEUSS_SaveMS(EMUFILE*, int) in state.o
"_inflateEnd", referenced from: _unzCloseCurrentFile in unzip.o
"_inflate", referenced from: _unzReadCurrentFile in unzip.o
"inflateInit2", referenced from: _unzOpenCurrentFile in unzip.o
"_gzgetc", referenced from: FCEU_fopen(char const*, char const*, char*, char*, int, char const**)in file.o
"_gzopen", referenced from: FCEU_fopen(char const*, char const*, char*, char*, int, char const**)in file.o
"_gzread", referenced from: FCEU_fopen(char const*, char const*, char*, char*, int, char const**)in file.o
"_gzseek", referenced from: FCEU_fopen(char const*, char const*, char*, char*, int, char const*)in file.o 
ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: ** [src/fceux] Error 1 scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Those are zlib functions. It seems like it is loading the zlib.h ok, but the symbols aren't being linked in? Just to make sure I downloaded the latest zlib and did a make install, no help. I have no clue what's going on here, it seems like it should be pretty basic, that library is nothing special. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the link list:

```
    scons: done reading SConscript files.
    scons: Building targets ...
    g++ -o src/fceux -Wl,-framework,Cocoa src/asm.o src/cart.o src/cheat.o src/conddebug.o src/config.o src/debug.o src/drawing.o src/emufile.o src/fceu.o src/fds.o src/file.o src/filter.o src/ines.o src/input.o src/netplay.o src/nsf.o src/oldmovie.o src/palette.o src/ppu.o src/sound.o src/state.o src/unif.o src/video.o src/vsuni.o src/wave.o src/x6502.o src/movie.o src/lua-engine.o src/boards/01-222.o src/boards/103.o src/boards/106.o src/boards/108.o src/boards/112.o src/boards/117.o src/boards/120.o src/boards/121.o src/boards/15.o src/boards/164.o src/boards/175.o src/boards/176.o src/boards/177.o src/boards/178.o src/boards/179.o src/boards/183.o src/boards/185.o src/boards/186.o src/boards/187.o src/boards/189.o src/boards/199.o src/boards/208.o src/boards/222.o src/boards/23.o src/boards/235.o src/boards/253.o src/boards/3d-block.o src/boards/411120-c.o src/boards/43.o src/boards/57.o src/boards/603-5052.o src/boards/68.o src/boards/8157.o src/boards/8237.o src/boards/830118C.o src/boards/88.o src/boards/90.o src/boards/95.o src/boards/a9711.o src/boards/a9746.o src/boards/addrlatch.o src/boards/ax5705.o src/boards/bandai.o src/boards/bmc13in1jy110.o src/boards/bmc42in1r.o src/boards/bmc64in1nr.o src/boards/bmc70in1.o src/boards/bonza.o src/boards/bs-5.o src/boards/copyfami_mmc3.o src/boards/dance.o src/boards/datalatch.o src/boards/deirom.o src/boards/dream.o src/boards/__dummy_mapper.o src/boards/edu2000.o src/boards/fk23c.o src/boards/ghostbusters63in1.o src/boards/gs-2004.o src/boards/gs-2013.o src/boards/h2288.o src/boards/karaoke.o src/boards/kof97.o src/boards/konami-qtai.o src/boards/ks7032.o src/boards/malee.o src/boards/mmc1.o src/boards/mmc3.o src/boards/mmc5.o src/boards/n-c22m.o src/boards/n106.o src/boards/n625092.o src/boards/novel.o src/boards/sachen.o src/boards/sc-127.o src/boards/sheroes.o src/boards/sl1632.o src/boards/smb2j.o src/boards/subor.o src/boards/super24.o src/boards/supervision.o src/boards/t-227-1.o src/boards/t-262.o src/boards/tengen.o src/boards/tf-1201.o src/drivers/common/args.o src/drivers/common/cheat.o src/drivers/common/config.o src/drivers/common/hq2x.o src/drivers/common/hq3x.o src/drivers/common/scale2x.o src/drivers/common/scale3x.o src/drivers/common/scalebit.o src/drivers/common/vidblit.o src/drivers/common/configSys.o src/drivers/common/nes_ntsc.o src/input/arkanoid.o src/input/bworld.o src/input/cursor.o src/input/fkb.o src/input/ftrainer.o src/input/hypershot.o src/input/mahjong.o src/input/mouse.o src/input/oekakids.o src/input/powerpad.o src/input/quiz.o src/input/shadow.o src/input/suborkb.o src/input/toprider.o src/input/zapper.o src/utils/crc32.o src/utils/endian.o src/utils/general.o src/utils/guid.o src/utils/md5.o src/utils/memory.o src/utils/unzip.o src/utils/xstring.o src/mappers/151.o src/mappers/16.o src/mappers/17.o src/mappers/18.o src/mappers/193.o src/mappers/201.o src/mappers/202.o src/mappers/203.o src/mappers/204.o src/mappers/212.o src/mappers/213.o src/mappers/214.o src/mappers/215.o src/mappers/217.o src/mappers/21.o src/mappers/225.o src/mappers/227.o src/mappers/228.o src/mappers/229.o src/mappers/22.o src/mappers/230.o src/mappers/231.o src/mappers/232.o src/mappers/234.o src/mappers/241.o src/mappers/242.o src/mappers/244.o src/mappers/246.o src/mappers/24and26.o src/mappers/255.o src/mappers/25.o src/mappers/27.o src/mappers/32.o src/mappers/33.o src/mappers/40.o src/mappers/41.o src/mappers/42.o src/mappers/46.o src/mappers/50.o src/mappers/51.o src/mappers/59.o src/mappers/60.o src/mappers/61.o src/mappers/62.o src/mappers/65.o src/mappers/67.o src/mappers/69.o src/mappers/6.o src/mappers/71.o src/mappers/72.o src/mappers/73.o src/mappers/75.o src/mappers/76.o src/mappers/77.o src/mappers/79.o src/mappers/80.o src/mappers/82.o src/mappers/83.o src/mappers/85.o src/mappers/86.o src/mappers/89.o src/mappers/8.o src/mappers/91.o src/mappers/92.o src/mappers/97.o src/mappers/99.o src/mappers/emu2413.o src/mappers/mmc2and4.o src/mappers/simple.o src/lua/src/lapi.o src/lua/src/lauxlib.o src/lua/src/lbaselib.o src/lua/src/lcode.o src/lua/src/ldblib.o src/lua/src/ldebug.o src/lua/src/ldo.o src/lua/src/ldump.o src/lua/src/lfunc.o src/lua/src/lgc.o src/lua/src/linit.o src/lua/src/liolib.o src/lua/src/llex.o src/lua/src/lmathlib.o src/lua/src/lmem.o src/lua/src/loadlib.o src/lua/src/lobject.o src/lua/src/lopcodes.o src/lua/src/loslib.o src/lua/src/lparser.o src/lua/src/lstate.o src/lua/src/lstring.o src/lua/src/lstrlib.o src/lua/src/ltable.o src/lua/src/ltablib.o src/lua/src/ltm.o src/lua/src/lundump.o src/lua/src/lvm.o src/lua/src/lzio.o src/lua/src/print.o src/drivers/sdl/input.o src/drivers/sdl/config.o src/drivers/sdl/sdl.o src/drivers/sdl/sdl-joystick.o src/drivers/sdl/sdl-sound.o src/drivers/sdl/sdl-throttle.o src/drivers/sdl/sdl-video.o src/drivers/sdl/unix-netplay.o 
-L/usr/local/lib
-lgtk-quartz-2.0
-lgdk-quartz-2.0
-latk-1.0
-lgio-2.0
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
-lpangocairo-1.0
-lpango-1.0
-lcairo
-lgobject-2.0
-lgmodule-2.0
-lgthread-2.0
-lglib-2.0
-lintl
-lSDLmain
-lSDL
```

SConstruct file:

```
import os
import sys
import platform 

opts = Variables()
opts.AddVariables(
  BoolVariable('FRAMESKIP', 'Enable frameskipping', 1),
  BoolVariable('OPENGL',    'Enable OpenGL support', 1),
  BoolVariable('LSB_FIRST', 'Least signficant byte first (non-PPC)', 1),
  BoolVariable('DEBUG',     'Build with debugging symbols', 1),
  BoolVariable('LUA',       'Enable Lua support', 1),
  BoolVariable('NEWPPU',    'Enable new PPU core', 1),
  BoolVariable('CREATE_AVI', 'Enable avi creation support (SDL only)', 0),
  BoolVariable('LOGO', 'Enable a logoscreen when creating avis (SDL only)', '1'),
  BoolVariable('GTK', 'Enable GTK2 GUI (SDL only)', 1),
  BoolVariable('GTK_LITE', 'Enable GTK2 for dialogs only', 0)
)

env = Environment(options = opts)

# LSB_FIRST must be off for PPC to compile
if platform.system == "ppc":
  env['LSB_FIRST'] = 0

# Default compiler flags:
env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['-Wall', '-Wno-write-strings', '-Wno-sign-compare', '-O2', '-Isrc/lua/src'])

if os.environ.has_key('PLATFORM'):
  env.Replace(PLATFORM = os.environ['PLATFORM'])
if os.environ.has_key('CC'):
  env.Replace(CC = os.environ['CC'])
if os.environ.has_key('CXX'):
  env.Replace(CXX = os.environ['CXX'])
if os.environ.has_key('WINDRES'):
  env.Replace(WINDRES = os.environ['WINDRES'])
if os.environ.has_key('CFLAGS'):
  env.Append(CCFLAGS = os.environ['CFLAGS'].split())
if os.environ.has_key('LDFLAGS'):
  env.Append(LINKFLAGS = os.environ['LDFLAGS'].split())

print "platform: ", env['PLATFORM']

# special flags for cygwin
# we have to do this here so that the function and lib checks will go through mingw
if env['PLATFORM'] == 'cygwin':
  env.Append(CCFLAGS = " -mno-cygwin")
  env.Append(LINKFLAGS = " -mno-cygwin")
  env['LIBS'] = ['wsock32'];

if env['PLATFORM'] == 'win32':
  env.Append(CPPPATH = [".", "drivers/win/", "drivers/common/", "drivers/", "drivers/win/zlib", "drivers/win/directx", "drivers/win/lua/include"])
  env.Append(CPPDEFINES = ["PSS_STYLE=2", "WIN32", "_USE_SHARED_MEMORY_", "NETWORK", "FCEUDEF_DEBUGGER", "NOMINMAX", "NEED_MINGW_HACKS", "_WIN32_IE=0x0600"])
  env.Append(LIBS = ["rpcrt4", "comctl32", "vfw32", "winmm", "ws2_32", "comdlg32", "ole32", "gdi32", "htmlhelp"])
else:
  conf = Configure(env)
  if not conf.CheckLib('SDL'):
    print 'Did not find libSDL or SDL.lib, exiting!'
    Exit(1)
  if env['GTK'] or env['GTK_LITE']:
    # Add compiler and linker flags from pkg-config
    env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0')
    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["_GTK2"])
  if env['GTK']:
    env.Append(CCFLAGS = ["-D_GTK"])
    env.Append(CCFLAGS =["-D_GTK_LITE"])
  if env['GTK_LITE']:
    env.Append(CCFLAGS =["-D_GTK_LITE"])

  ### Lua platform defines
  ### Applies to all files even though only lua needs it, but should be ok
  if env['LUA']:
    if env['PLATFORM'] == 'darwin':
      # Define LUA_USE_MACOSX otherwise we can't bind external libs from lua
      env.Append(CCFLAGS = ["-DLUA_USE_MACOSX"])      
    if env['PLATFORM'] == 'posix':
      # If we're POSIX, we use LUA_USE_LINUX since that combines usual lua posix defines with dlfcn calls for dynamic library loading.
      # Should work on any *nix
      env.Append(CCFLAGS = ["-DLUA_USE_LINUX"])

  ### Search for gd if we're not in Windows
  if env['PLATFORM'] != 'win32' and env['PLATFORM'] != 'cygwin' and env['CREATE_AVI'] and env['LOGO']:
    gd = conf.CheckLib('gd', autoadd=1)
    if gd == 0:
      env['LOGO'] = 0
      print 'Did not find libgd, you won\'t be able to create a logo screen for your avis.'

  if conf.CheckFunc('asprintf'):
    conf.env.Append(CCFLAGS = "-DHAVE_ASPRINTF")
  if env['OPENGL'] and conf.CheckLibWithHeader('GL', 'GL/gl.h', 'c++', autoadd=1):
    conf.env.Append(CCFLAGS = "-DOPENGL")
  conf.env.Append(CPPDEFINES = ['PSS_STYLE=1'])
  # parse SDL cflags/libs
  env.ParseConfig('sdl-config --cflags --libs')

  env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["_S9XLUA_H"])
  env = conf.Finish()

if sys.byteorder == 'little' or env['PLATFORM'] == 'win32':
  env.Append(CPPDEFINES = ['LSB_FIRST'])

if env['FRAMESKIP']:
  env.Append(CPPDEFINES = ['FRAMESKIP'])

print "base CPPDEFINES:",env['CPPDEFINES']
print "base CCFLAGS:",env['CCFLAGS']

if env['DEBUG']:
  env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["_DEBUG"], CCFLAGS = ['-g'])

if env['PLATFORM'] != 'win32' and env['PLATFORM'] != 'cygwin' and env['CREATE_AVI']:
  env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["CREATE_AVI"])
else:
  env['CREATE_AVI']=0;

Export('env')
SConscript('src/SConscript')

# Install rules
exe_suffix = ''
if env['PLATFORM'] == 'win32':
  exe_suffix = '.exe'

fceux_src = 'src/fceux' + exe_suffix
fceux_dst = 'bin/fceux' + exe_suffix

auxlib_src = 'src/auxlib.lua'
auxlib_dst = 'bin/auxlib.lua'

fceux_h_src = 'src/drivers/win/help/fceux.chm'
fceux_h_dst = 'bin/fceux.chm'

env.Command(fceux_h_dst, fceux_h_src, [Copy(fceux_h_dst, fceux_h_src)])
env.Command(fceux_dst, fceux_src, [Copy(fceux_dst, fceux_src)])
env.Command(auxlib_dst, auxlib_src, [Copy(auxlib_dst, auxlib_src)])

# TODO: Fix this build script to gracefully install auxlib and the man page
#env.Alias(target="install", source=env.Install(dir="/usr/local/bin/", source=("bin/fceux", "bin/auxlib.lua")))
env.Alias(target="install", source=env.Install(dir="/usr/local/bin/", source="bin/fceux"))
```

Comment: When you are building your NES Emulator, is your zlib lib in a directory that the linker can find?

Comment: It looks like you are missing `-lz`.  Can you show up the link line?

Comment: Besides -lz in the link line, depending on where libz was installed, you may need to have a -L/directory, such as -L/usr/local/lib.    Or add that directory to the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I sometimes have the same problem, but it is due to the fact the a lib is compiled 32bits only and my app is 64bits, or vice-versa.  The output you posted above is not enough to tell if that's what happening.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think it IS the -lz missing...but the only problem now is I don't know how to add it, because there seems to be no actual Makefile.  I think scons generates it or something, and I'm not sure how to add it in.  I added the SConstruct file to the question.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug into scons to find my answer.

I added this to the SConstruct file (in one of the non-win32 sections):

```
env['LIBS'] = ['z']
```

Think this would be worth mentioning to the FCE team or is this something that typically isn't a problem on linux machines?

Comment: Yes, it would be worth mentioning to the maintainers.